# Changing state based on parameter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to learn react and am spending way too much time on something very minimal.
I have 3 tabs and whichever tab is active is highlighted. The inactive tabs show a number next to them to let the user know how many items are under the tab. On page load this shows correctly, but I want these rules to apply as the tabs are clicked.

I am initiating my state like so:

```
this.state = {
  selectedAlert: { error: false, warning: true, success: true },
}
```

I am rendering the tabs like so:

```
       <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={() => this.updateAlerts('error')}>
        { this.state.selectedAlert.error ? <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-danger">3</span> : null}
        Errors
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={() => this.updateAlerts('warning')}>
        { this.state.selectedAlert.warning ? <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-warning">4</span> : null }
        Warnings
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={() => this.updateAlerts('success')}>
        { this.state.selectedAlert.success ? <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-success">8</span> : null }
        Acheivements
      </li>
```

And the function is defined like so:

```
updateAlerts(selected){
  this.setState({
    selectedAlert: {error: true, warning: true, success: true,}
  })
this.state.selectedAlert[selected] = false;
```

}

However when another tab is clicked all the notification numbers show up regardless of the tab, and when i console log the state property things get even weirder.
Say I only click the second tab, now at the end of the function the first 2 values are set to false, with the tab I have not clicked yet still set to true. (even though now all 3 notifications are showing up as if they were all set to true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code behaves like that is because `this.setState()` is asynchronous which means that `this.state.selectedAlert[selected] = false` line will be executed BEFORE `this.setState()` will actually set the state so `this.setState()` will override the state set by `this.state.selectedAlert[selected] = false`.

That is why `updateAlerts` function should look like this:

```
updateAlerts(selected){
  this.setState({
    selectedAlert: {error: true, warning: true, success: true, [selected]: false}
  });
}
```

Also, do not modify `this.state` directly, always use `this.setState()`. Mutating state directly can lead to bugs optimization issues. React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) say:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

And it actually happened in your code.
Also, here is a good article about state mutation - https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly .

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried this as well and to no avail, i get the same outcome as mentioned above.

Comment: Okay i tried it again to verify and it works now. So I must be mistaken or have had typed incorrectly the first time, sorry and thank you! This works.

Comment: @wynx I have also edited my answer with the elaboration on why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1):

binding event is necessary to make `this` work in the callback, below an example:

```
export default class Index extends React.Component 
{

    constructor()
    {

        this.state = {
            selectedAlert: { error: false, warning: true, success: true },
        }

        this.updateAlerts = this.updateAlerts.bind(this);
    }

    updateAlerts(selected)
    {
        this.setState({
           selectedAlert: {
              error: (selected === 'error'), 
              warning: (selected === 'warning'), 
              success: (selected === 'success')
           }
        })
    }

    render()
    {
        return(.......)
    }

}
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: @wynix code is correct on that matter, because the `updatedAlerts` functions is called inside an array function, which already binds the component's context correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do a little refactoring... There's no need to keep track of all the alert types inside the state. You can simplify it a lot, and consequentially, the `updateAlerts` function too.

```js
const ERROR = 'error';
const WARNING = 'warning';
const SUCCESS = 'success';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      selected: ERROR
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={this.updateAlerts(ERROR)}>
            {
              selected !== ERROR && (
              <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-danger">3</span>)
            }
            Errors
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={this.updateAlerts(WARNING)}>
            {
              selected !== WARNING && (
                <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-warning">4</span>)
            }
            Warnings
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item m-tabs__item" onClick={this.updateAlerts(SUCCESS)}>
            {
              selected !== SUCCESS && (
                <span className="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--accent bg-success">8</span>)
            }
            Achievements
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div className="contents">
          {selected === ERROR && (
            <section>
              ERRORS TAB ACTIVE
            </section>
          )}
          
          {selected === WARNING && (
            <section>
              WARNING TAB ACTIVE
            </section>
          )}
          
          {selected === SUCCESS && (
            <section>
              ACHIEVEMENTS TAB ACTIVE
            </section>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  updateAlerts(selected) {
    return () => this.setState({ selected })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('main'));
```

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px; 
}

ul li span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.contents {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main/>
```